# Remove textarea's box shadow on bottom only

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is what I currently have:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ZENupsr.png]

What I'm trying to do is remove the bottom box-shadow of the textarea (the one just above the B, I, and U) so that it ends up looking like this:

[image]

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/7616/

HTML:

```
<div class="editor span4">
  <textarea class="span4"></textarea>
  <ul class="format-post">
    <li><b>B</b></li>
    <li><i>I</i></li>
    <li><u>U</u></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

body {
  margin: 10px;
}

textarea {
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
  border-bottom-color: #eee;
}

textarea:focus {
  border-bottom-color: #eeeeee;
}

textarea:focus + .format-post {
  border-color: rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 7px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
  transition: border 0.2s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.2s linear 0s;
}

.format-post {
  list-style: none;
  background: #fafafa;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-top: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.format-post li {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-right: 1px solid #eee;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 33px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the `box-shadow` to

```
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 
0 -4px 7px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
```

and it worked! :)

The bottom color was still blue, so I just changed it to

```
border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
```

You can change it if needed! :)

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/MgcDU/7617/

Pardon me, I just saw that you want the textarea to be colored, which doesn't fit for the question. You're saying in title to remove the border-bottom. But in answer you're having bottom border for both.

If you want to get the border and all animation when textarea is not active, then remove `:focus` and it will do the job.

And I am still very sorry, for unclear answer because I am not able to get it, which should be answered the question or the answer.

Comment: I just saw your JSFiddle. It's not how I need it to look. Please look at my images again.

Comment: I have updated the answer..and please feel free to get back for more :0

Comment: I'm not trying to remove any borders, I'm trying to remove the bottom box-shadow of the textarea (above the B, I, and U).